# C# array static field

Tags: c#, arraylist, static

I 've just started writing a little app. I made things work now I am in plan to do everything what is needed better. I've discovered one mistake.
I have a class with static field which is an arraylist and its access is public.
Other classes uses it and I m wondering what would be the best option to get acces from other classes to this field.
First what I have in mind its just getter returning this list. 
But I have no other ideas what could beanother option I decided to ask.

Greetings,
Betty

Comment: If it is really an *ArrayList* then your first error is that you are using *ArrayList* in 2017. Use *List<yourtype>*

Comment: Does the  class containing the ArrayList need to be used in a non-static way? I'm guessing the way you are currently getting the ArrayList is through "objectName.arrayListName". It really depends what you are using the ArrayList for. Please post up a summary of how you intend to use the ArrayList. Also consider using a List rather than ArrayList.

Comment: Show us some code, then we can help. Other then that, when it comes to accessibility with collections, I generally want to create my own getters, setters and adders depending on what functionality is required.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a different ways, this is one of them:

```
public class TestService
{
    private static readonly List<string> list = new List<string>();

    public IEnumerable<string> List
    {
        get { return list; }
    }

    //list manipulation methods...
}
```

Basically, you should prevent manipulation (i.e. add/update/remove items) on that list from outside of the class. Mainly because that class should be **only** responsible for direct list manipulation.

So, that's the reason behind `IEnumerable<string>` type. Do not misuse `List<string>` casting on this property!

Now when you are sure that list can't be directly manipulated from the outside of the class, you should expose public methods inside `TestService` class. Each method should only have one responsibility and reason to change ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)), in other words, you should have separate methods for adding, updating and removing items.